# How can I better improve this SQL query?

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `people` 
WHERE   `Cars` BETWEEN '0' AND '1' 
AND     `Name` LIKE ('%George%') 
    OR  `Address` LIKE ('%George%') 
    OR  `City` LIKE ('%George%') 
ORDER BY Favorite DESC
```

Currently it returns people who have `2 cars` if their `address` has `George` in it or their `city` is `Georgetown`.

How can I make it so it would return only people who have `0` to `1` cars and their name is George or Town is George?

So I think I'm using the wrong `OR` statement? However I'm having difficultly improving the statement.
Any suggestions would be lovely.

Comment: *"How can I better improve this SQL query?"* - You post it on code review  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or DB Exchange http://dba.stackexchange.com/ - Your question's title is misleading.

Comment: `Address` = 'George'` or `'Address' LIKE ('George')`

Comment: do you really need `like`

Comment: Use `()` to group your `AND/OR` statements.

Comment: people who have 2 cars `BETWEEN '0' AND '1'` Dont get it

Comment: @Mihai He's saying that people with 2 cars are appearing in the results, but he only wants 0 or 1.  The problem is that he doesn't have his `AND` and `OR` statements properly grouped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `parenthesis` in `where` clause to filter the rows properly.

In your query even if the `Cars` is not between `0` and `1` and if `Address LIKE ('%George%')` then that row will be returned because `and` operator is applied only between `name` and `cars`.

To avoid this just add `parenthesis` to the columns with `OR` operator.Try this.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `people` 
WHERE   `Cars` BETWEEN '0' AND '1' 
AND     (`Name` LIKE ('%George%') 
    OR  `Address` LIKE ('%George%') 
    OR  `City` LIKE ('%George%')) 
ORDER BY Favorite DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are getting is that `and` has a higher precendence than `or`.

Your query is being interpreted as:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `people` 
WHERE   (
            `Cars` BETWEEN '0' AND '1' 
            AND     `Name` LIKE ('%George%')
        ) 
        OR  `Address` LIKE ('%George%') 
        OR  `City` LIKE ('%George%')) 
        ORDER BY Favorite DESC
```

The query is better written with the `or` clauses inside parentheses:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `people` 
WHERE   `Cars` BETWEEN '0' AND '1' 
AND     (
            `Name` LIKE ('%George%') 
            OR  `Address` LIKE ('%George%') 
            OR  `City` LIKE ('%George%')
        )
ORDER BY Favorite DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Group the OR statements in `()` so that one of them must be true:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `people` 
WHERE   `Cars` BETWEEN '0' AND '1' 
AND     (
        `Name` LIKE ('%George%') OR
        `Address` LIKE ('%George%') OR
        `City` LIKE ('%George%')
        )
ORDER BY Favorite DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously no. of cars can't be fractional so in should be used to check for 0 or 1

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `people` 
WHERE   `Cars` in(0,1) 
AND     (`Name` LIKE ('%George%') 
    OR  `Address` LIKE ('%George%') 
    OR  `City` LIKE ('%George%')) 
ORDER BY Favorite DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try add "()":

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `people` 
WHERE   `Cars` BETWEEN '0' AND '1' 
AND     (`Name` LIKE ('%George%') 
    OR  `Address` LIKE ('%George%') 
    OR  `City` LIKE ('%George%') )
ORDER BY Favorite DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can fetch by one column only and be able to add more data later on..
what I mean is that add new column called "search" and throw all the data you want and search only by this.

```
SELECT  * FROM    `people` 
WHERE   `Cars` BETWEEN '0' AND '1' 
AND     `search` LIKE ('%George%')
ORDER BY Favorite DESC
```

keep in mind that if something has been updated you need to update the "search" value also with the new data.